# Showing a group of observation is standard normally distributed

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $X_1,X_2\dots$ be a sequence of independent RVs such that $X_{n}$ is binomial with parameters $2n - 1$
and $1/2$. Define
$$Y_{n}=\frac{2(X_{1}+X_{2}+\cdots+X_{n})}{n} -n$$

Show
$P[Y_{n}<t]\to \displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^t\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac {x^2}{2}}\, dx $ as $n\to\infty$.

I'm trying to show it by computing the moment generating function and am having trouble.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** write the binomial RVs as sum of independant Bernoulli variables of parameter $\frac 12$. Then apply the CLT.

Comment: The expected value I got was 1-n and the variance to be 1/n. Is that correct?

Comment: the expected value is false, at least.